# Existence of a global analytic solution to a linear first order PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, linear-pde

Let $B=\lbrace \|z\|<1\rbrace$ be a unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^n, n\geq 2.$ Let
$f_1,\cdots, f_n, f$ be holomorphic functions on $B.$ Now, consider the following
first order, linear PDE:
$$f_1\partial_{z_1}(y)+\cdots +f_n\partial_{z_n}(y)+fy=0.$$
Here is my question. Is there some non-degeneracy condition of functions $f_1,\cdots, f_n$ that implies existence of a nontrivial solution $y$ which is holomorphic on $B?$
From what I understand about the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem, if $f_1,\cdots, f_n$ have no common zero, then for any $w\in B$ there exists a nontrivial holomorphic
solution (in fact infinitely many) defined near $w.$ But, I don't see how to get a global solution from it.Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If the holomorphic vector field $X=\sum_i f_i\partial_{z_i}$ has no zeroes and there is a complex hypersurface nowhere tangent to it, and each point lies on a unique trajectory of that vector field through that hypersurface, then the differential equation becomes a linear ordinary differential equation for a holomorphic parameterization of each trajectory, so has global solvability. So you need to find your nowhere tangent hypersurface, and prove, for each point, both existence and uniqueness of a trajectory through that hypersurface and through that point.

Comment: I see, thanks! But I don't quite see apriori how doable that is.